# How to allow only special characters as input?

Tags: ruby

How can I check if an entered input only has special characters? I tried the following, but its not working:

```
/^[\p{L}\s\p{N}._@?¿!¡€-]+$/
```

Comment: I want to use regexp only.

Comment: by special, you mean anything but alphabetic and numeric?

Comment: except alphabetic and numeric

Answer (score 2):

```
"!@#$%^&()!@" !~ /\w/  # => true
"!a@#$%^&()!@" !~ /\w/ # => false
```

Comment: I have no clue what OP claims to be “special chars,” but occasionally `"_" !~ /\w/ #=> false`.

Comment: In the comment, the OP says:  
except alphabetic and numeric. I agree it is not clear whether `_` is included.

Comment: BTW, there are spanish punctuation signs (¿?) in the example, that’s why I assume exotics like ñ and ç should be matched as letters.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?:

```
/^[^A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

The pattern matches from the beginning to the end of the string and allows one or more characters which are not a letter or a number.

Answer (score 0):

This will match anything that contains only non-word characters (anything but alpha-numeric)

```
/^[\W]+$/
```

//edit it also doesn't match _

Answer (score 0):

To check whether an input contains only digits and letters *from any alphabet*, one might use [`\p{Alnum}` matcher](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Alternation)

```
▶ '¡Hello!' !~ /^\p{Alnum}+$/
#=> false
▶ 'Hello' !~ /^\p{Alnum}+$/
#=> true
▶ '¿Привет?' !~ /^\p{Alnum}+$/
#=> false
▶ 'Привет' !~ /^\p{Alnum}+$/
#=> true
```

That said, to check for non-alphanumerics:

```
▶ not '!@#$%^&()!@' !~ /^[^\p{Alnum}]+$/
#=> true
▶ not 'a!@#$%^&()!@' !~ /^[^\p{Alnum}]+$/
#=> false
```